# What is the default size unit in Linux' ls -l command

Tags: linux

I wanted to know what the unit (bytes, bits, kb) of the output of the `ls -l` command in Linux is.

Here is an example of what I've got:

```
-rw-rw-r--    1 guest    guest       39870 Feb 14 19:41 ser_cat
-rw-r--r--    1 guest    guest       19935 Feb 14 19:35 ser_cp
-rw-rw-r--    1 guest    guest       19935 Feb 14 19:29 ser_more
```

What is the unit of 39870 (the size of `ser_cat`)?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

That size is in bytes.

You can use `ls -lh` to print the long listing with human readable file sizes.

Comment: Just a note on the units:  ls -h gives 1K (1024 bytes).    ls --si gives 1k (1000 bytes).

Comment: @ThomasBratt Are you sure? On Debian 10 here, `-h` seems to give decimal SI units (Gigabytes, Megabytes and Kilobytes). `exa` shows the same figures/units by default and I get the binary units (Gibibytes, Mebibytes and Kibibytes), resulting in smaller integers, using the `-b` switch.

Answer (score 4):

We need to add `l` (long listing option) to show human-readable file sizes (`ls -lh`). In your case, size of file `ser_cat` is in 39870 **bytes**.

```
-rw-rw-r--    1 guest    guest       39870 Feb 14 19:41 ser_cat
-rw-r--r--    1 guest    guest       19935 Feb 14 19:35 ser_cp
-rw-rw-r--    1 guest    guest       19935 Feb 14 19:29 ser_more
```

`ls -lh` command shows all file size information as K for Kibibyte (KiB), M for Mebibyte (MiB) and so on. See [this](http://superuser.com/questions/287498/what-is-the-difference-between-a-kibibyte-a-kilobit-and-a-kilobyte) for the difference between kibi and kilo.

Instead of bits they show information in bytes.

`ls -lh` shows unit (size) information using single character instead of two characters. If no unit information is there, then it means bytes.

Comment: The units for -h are actually Kibibytes and Mebibytes, not Kilobytes and Megabytes. If you want Kilobytes and Megabytes, use `--si` instead.

Comment: Updated post to reflect @Ajedi32 point.  , Refer  [http://superuser.com/questions/287498/what-is-the-difference-between-a-kibibyte-a-kilobit-and-a-kilobyte][post] to understand Differences between KiB and KB