# How to fix Nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04 to show 1MB = Division by 1024 kb?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nautilus

How to force Nautilus in Ubuntu 14.04 to show correct size of file(s) in Megabytes, which is divided by 1024 kilobytes, instead of 1000 which it does at present?

Comment: A "megabyte" ***is*** 1000 kilobytes —  see [What is the difference between a kibibyte, a kilobit, and a kilobyte?](http://superuser.com/q/287498/150988)

Comment: Also, in what program ?

Comment: 1.However, in the computer and information technology fields, several other definitions are used that arose for historical reasons of convenience. A common usage has been to designate one megabyte as 1048576 bytes.
2.In Nautilus