# partition doesn't match the size I specified it to be

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning

I created a disk partition on my USB with the size of 100MB.
I used `fdisk` and `mkfs` commands.

I noticed that the size of partition isn't actually 100MB, but 104.9MB. I am wondering, why partition doesn't match the size I told it to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of [different units](https://superuser.com/q/287498/432690).

> `1 MiB (Mebibyte) = 1,048,576 B (Bytes) (2^20 Bytes)`

In your case `100 MiB = 104857600 B ≈ 104.9 MB`.