# Ubuntu says 993GB, Windows says 930GB. Which one to beleive?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, storage

I recently purchased an external Hard Drive with 1TB if storage capacity.
The only problem here is when I'm in Windows 7, it shows that it has 930GB available but on Ubuntu it's 993GB. The HDD is partitioned as NTFS.
Which one says the truth?

Comment: Where do you see those capacities ? You might be confusing formatted space versus drive capacity.

Comment: [This may be of assistance](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UnitsPolicy)...

Comment: @BatchyX I simply open up the properties window of the mounted drive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, Windows always calculate hard drives as **powers of 1024** while hard drive manufacturers use **powers of 1000**. On other hand Ubuntu uses the **Standard** 1000 division.

Most **manufacturers** of hard disk drives define,

```
1 TB = 1000000000000 bytes = 10^12 bytes
```

While Ubuntu and Windows see it as:

> 1000000000000/1024*1024*1024 = 931 **GB**   (Windows style) (should be **[gibibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte) (GiB)**)
>
> 1000000000000/1000*1000*1000 = 1000 **GB**   (Ubuntu style)

Ubuntu is showing capacity as **993 GB**, because that missing space might be used up by the allocation table and other meta data.

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte#Consumer_confusion) wiki article explains the issue :

> Microsoft Windows reports size in **gigabytes** by dividing the **total
>   capacity** in bytes by 1073741824, while **still reporting** the result with
>   the symbol "**GB**". This practice is a **cause of confusion**, as a hard
>   disk with an advertised capacity of, for example, "400 GB" (meaning
>   400000000000bytes) might be reported by the operating system as only
>   "372 GB". Other software, like Mac OS X 10.6 and some components of
>   the **Linux kernel** measure using the **decimal units**.

[This](https://superuser.com/a/373601/153937) SU answer is a very good Explanation on Storage Size Calculation.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad, to be of help :)