# file size of folder matches from server to hard drive but the total size doesn't match when converting in Google?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems

I looked around and saw similar questions but different situations. I have folder on a server uploaded by a vendor with 224,199 files for a total size of: 280,447,323,973 bytes (I see this through FileZilla) which Google converts to 280.xx GB.

When I check the folder on my windows 7 NTFS hard drive the byte and files match but the total GB is different what I see in properties is: 261 GB

The files were transferring slowly over the weekend at my office the power had gone out so I was checking to see if all the files moved over and it appears it has, but the total size in GB doesn't match what I see in Google. I am converting from bytes to GB.

[image: filezilla screenshot] vs [image: hard drive properties screenshot]

Google:

[image: google screenshot]

Any ideas?

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it true that 1 MB can mean either 1000000 bytes, 1024000 bytes, or 1048576 bytes?](https://superuser.com/questions/373579/is-it-true-that-1-mb-can-mean-either-1000000-bytes-1024000-bytes-or-1048576-by)

Comment: 280447323973 B ≈ 280 GB ≈ 261 GiB.

Comment: Hi @KamilMaciorowski does that mean NTFS on Windows 7 displays in GiB despite the properties displaying GB ?

Comment: Yes. The accepted and highly upvoted answer to the duplicate question explicitly says so, that's why I gave you the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the size of sectors. Large sizes waste space on the disk because parts of each sector may be empty (but storage is faster). The size on disk is irrelevant, unless it were *smaller* than the actual file size, though even that is possible with disk compression.

If you have reason to question the validity of a file, download it and diff (or at least compare checksum) with a known good file.

Comment: thank you Dr Moishe, that's a good idea. I was concerned maybe the files were corrupted and the entire file wasn't transfered or something due tothe power outage but loading the folder in this external seagate drive is insanely slow took 20 minutes to load just half of it. I'll give your suggestion a shot. appreciate it!