# Is the file size of the file manager more accurate or from du?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, size

### The Problem

I'm currently playing with some VMs and made a backup by exporting the VM in the Open Virtualization Format 2.0 because nested snapshots take too much space.

When I checked the taken space of the ova file with `du -ah` I've noticed that the backup file takes 5.8G but when looking at the file via file manager it displays 6.2GB.

I know `du` doesn't displays the actual file size but disk space block size allocated to the file so the output size can always be greater than the actual file. Does that mean that the file manager is inaccurate? Is there a way to reduce the displayed file size discrepancy?

So far I couldn't find any posts on forums about this occurrence.

### The System Details

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

I use the ext4 filesystem. The block size of the filesystem is 4096 Bytes.
I use the simple file manager "Files" for GNOME. Version 3.36.3-stable.

The output of `du --version` is:

du (GNU coreutils) 8.30

Would appreciate any help. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Most likely because [6.2 GB = 5.8 GiB](https://superuser.com/q/373579/432690). Broader picture: [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311/108618).

Comment: I see so that was the missing detail to understand it. Thank you for linking the explanations @KamilMaciorowski