# What unit does swapon use for size?

Tags: linux, swap

Both `swapon -show` and `cat /proc/swaps` report that I have a swap of size 1003516 and no unit is given. At first I assumed that this was bytes, giving me about 1 megabyte. However, `free -mh` reports that I have nearly 1 gigabyte. This has made me suspicious of the units in use. Does `swapon -show` give results in something other than bytes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987060/linux-command-swapon-and-its-unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note `swapon -show` is `swapon -s -h -o -w` and it seems it's just `swapon -s`. You probably wanted `swapon --show`.

In my Kubuntu `swapon --show` shows `16.5G` which is ambiguous (rounding; is `G` for [gigabyte or gibibyte](https://superuser.com/a/1077275/432690)?), but there's also unambiguous `swapon --show --bytes` (which I used to tell this `16.5G` was actually in gibibytes).

`cat /proc/swaps` should be more predictable (and `swapon -s` should be equivalent to `cat /proc/swaps`, but `-s` is deprecated in favor of `--show`). While some sources I found use the word "kilobytes" to describe `/proc/swaps`, on every machine I own it's actually in *kibibytes*, 1024-byte units.