# Crystal Disk Info: "Total Host Writes" shows two distinct values

Tags: windows, ssd, crystaldiskinfo

Crystal Disk Info shows two distinct values for `Total Host Writes` on my SSD when hovering over it, one of which is less than the other; which number of writes is correct?
[image: Sreenshot]

Comment: Well 1472 divided by 1024 does equal to 1.438 :)

Comment: Beware that some versions of CrystalDiskInfo include malware/adware OpenCandy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is the same number. If you look carefully the result is 1472 **GB** and in the pop-up is 1.438 **TB**, where according to the binary convention 1024 gigabytes equals 1 terabyte.

Formula:

```
1472 / 1024 = 1.4375 TB
```

---

You can find a more detailed post about the metrics [here](https://superuser.com/a/1077275/552853) .

Answer (score 7):

### Edit: It's not drive capacity but total bytes written.

It show the **capacity** of your drive in **different binary format** (in this case 1472 GiB 'GibiByte' and 1.438 TiB 'TebiByte').

For anyone looking to quickly convert between different format, just google

```
[NumberToConvert] [format in binary] to [format to convert to in binary]
```

ex: `1472 GiB to TiB` => `1.4375 TiB`

Make sure the dropdowns below the number are in the correct format too (Gibibyte and Tebibyte respectively. See screenshot below).

***I think Windows always display drive capacity in binary format while most drive manufacturers use decimal format in their ads. To convert from binary to decimal and viceversa, google as `1472 GiB to GB` (GB stands for 'GigaByte')

[Google image to convert binary format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL8VB.png)

Comment: That's not capacity, it's total bytes written.  Since a byte can be overwritten many times, it can be bigger than the drive size.  (In this case 512.1 GB).  But yes, it's using binary for those write-endurance numbers.

Comment: Sorry, must have misread it at first sight.