# Flash drives do not have the memory they're meant to have

Tags: usb, memory, usb-flash-drive

Whenever you buy a flash-drive, it always says it has 4GB, but when you plug it into a PC it says it has 3.72 GB, why is that?

I don't really care too much for the 200MB, but with my 512GB pen-drive, I lose 12GB of space and this is quite a lot. Does anyone know why this happens?