# How to display byte sizes with binary prefixes?

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, file-management, disk-management

For as long as I can remember, Microsoft DOS and Windows have been displaying byte sizes with decimal prefixes, instead of binary prefixes. This has plagued at least two generations of computer users over the years. There must be *at least* A<sup>6</sup> questions of the type "why is my X GB hard disk drive only showing Y GB?" on the web.

There is nothing wrong with using decimal prefixes to display byte sizes. Really! But when you use binary based size calculations and you prefix them with decimal prefixes, then it becomes a total wreckage!

Here is an example of what a 32 GB disk partition is displayed like in `diskpart` on Windows.

```
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary             29 GB  1024 KB
```

Is there a sane, logical reason for this? Why is Microsoft still keeping up with this bad practice in the latest Windows versions?

At very least, I think they should consider doing what Canonical is doing with Ubuntu Linux. They are using decimal prefixes, *and* decimal based calculations to display disk and file sizes. So in Ubuntu, a 500 GB disk will display as 500 GB. *Bah oui! Voilá!*

Here is what that same disk partition would be displayed like in `parted` in Ubuntu.

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  32.0GB  32.0GB  primary  fat32        lba
```

I would like to have a flipped version of the Ubuntu approach, where I have binary based size calculations and binary prefixes. How can this be done on Windows? Is there some hidden option or a registry hack for this? How about Linux?

Comment: For Ubuntu Try `df -h` vs `df --si`... :-) Those options work with `du` too

Comment: So this is not system-wide then on Linux? I will check out those commands. How about Windows?

Comment: @Hastur How do you set this for the entire system? Some environment setting? I don't want to be opening Terminal and running these commands each time I want the preferred read-out. Please post an answer if you know how to make this the preferred choice for the entire system.

Comment: just stating the obvious here, but a workaround is third party software. Or of it's just an EXE displaying byte sizes of partitions in the form you want then that's a very small program whether a GUI(like something easily written in visual studio). Or something in C# (adapting this) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a quick answer for *KDE*  4.13.3 under Kubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.
Search under:

> ```
> System Settings  
>    +---> Country/Region & Language   
>      +---> Other
>        +---> Byte Size and Unit
> ```

You can choose among

- **[IEC Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_80000-13)** (kiB,MiB,etc)   e.g. 2000 bytes = 1.95 KiB
- [JEDEC Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEDEC_memory_standards#Unit_prefixes_for_semiconductor_storage_capacity) (KB,MB,etc)   e.g. 2000 bytes = 1.95 KB
- [METRIC Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) (kB,MB,etc)  e.g. 2000 bytes = 2.00 kB

I'm quite sure that you can find similar option on each other Desktop Environments...

**Note:** The exact difference arises from the difference between the *"human"* 10<sup>3</sup>=1000 and the *"logic"* 2<sup>10</sup>=1024...

---

**Historical Note:**
**Vendors and Law**: 
We have this kind of confusion because vendors behave following market's rules, when laws do not force them to do otherwise. I mean that to say this HDD is 4 GB sells better then to say it is 3.78 GB. For the same reasons the internet providers often speak about *bps* and let you understand *Bps*. There is a factor 8: a Byte(**B**) is 8 bits(**b**).

The problem is that the laws exist, but not in all the nations are the same.

The **International System**, or ***SI***, is the most widely used in the world for commerce and science (It was published in 1960 and at present are partially out only USA that is adopting, Burma and Liberia).
It establishes not only the units of measurement but even the [prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units#Prefixes).

Since it is *natural* in the computer world the use of a numeric base in power of 2 (and not 10 as in *human world*) it was introduced in 1998 the system of the [binary prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix). Here directly the [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Specific_units_of_IEC_60027-2_A.2_and_ISO.2FIEC_80000). Nowadays we find  in the situation that

```
the International Electrotechnical Commission (IEC) and several other standards
(NIST...) and trade organizations approved standards and recommendations 
for a new set of binary prefixes that refer unambiguously to powers of 1024
```

When you read `1GB` it should be `1 000 000 Bytes`,
instead when you read `1GiB` it should be `1 073 741 824 Bytes`.

---

**Additional References**

- [Another answer about *why X GB hard disk drive only showing Y GB?*](https://superuser.com/a/758243/257269)
- [The International System of Units](http://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si_brochure_8_en.pdf) (SI) (8th ed.), ISBN 92-822-2213-6
- [Specific units of IEC 60027-2 A.2 and ISO/IEC 80000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#Specific_units_of_IEC_60027-2_A.2_and_ISO.2FIEC_80000)
- [NIST SP 330 for some appliance of SI in the United States](http://physics.nist.gov/Pubs/SP330/sp330.pdf)
- [Council Directive 71/354/EEC of 18 October 1971 on the approximation of the laws of the Member States relating to units of measurement](http://old.eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=DD:I:1971_III:31971L0354:EN:PDF)
- [Council Directive 80/181/EEC of 20 December 1979 on the approximation of the laws of the Member States relating to units of measurement and on the repeal of Directive 71/354/EEC](http://old.eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:1980:039:0040:0050:EN:PDF) and successive modifications
- [Timeline of binary prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_binary_prefixes)

Comment: I use Unity (GNOME), so I don't have that option. Where would one find this option in GNOME environment?

Comment: Microsoft is not using JEDEC prefixes though? Not from what I can tell. **1:** In Windows, *kilobyte* is is abbreviated as kB with a lower case letter, and it means 1024 byte. JEDEC assigns KB (with upper case letter) to mean 1024 byte. **2:** JEDEC defines KB, MB, and GB. Windows can display TB prefixes. So Windows is really using 1024 byte units and decimal prefixes or *SI* prefixes. Which I find somewhat disturbing.

Comment: I did a web search for `why my * GB disk drive only shows * GB` and found about 76 million hits! Google didn't like that so on the next query I only received 9 hits. It had filtered some of the hits as unrelated. Disabling the filter gave me 2.4 million hits. This is still more than the 1 million I predicted, and it shows how many people are confused about this. Majority of them are using Windows too.

Comment: From the BIPM paper: *"These SI prefixes refer strictly to powers of 10. They should not be used to indicate powers of 2 (for example, one kilobit represents 1000 bits and not 1024 bits)."* I think Microsoft needs to read this. :-)

Comment: Are you sure you have no  "System Settings...Country/Region & Language ... Units..." at all? BTW  which is the value of  your `$LC_MEASUREMENT`?

Comment: I do have "Language Support" where I have the "Language" and "Regional Formats" tabs. On the regional formats I can set "display numbers, dates an currency amounts" according to country setting and "apply system-wide".

Comment: For what it's worth, the `$LC_MEASUREMENT` is set to `sv_SE.UTF-8`. But how is this country specific? Also, how can I set only the byte size prefixes and size calculations, without affecting things like currency, date and time format and so on?

Comment: In your list of Kubuntu options, shouldn't JEDEC be 1.95 **KB** and metric 2.00 **kB**?